# Prevent Auto Rotate For Specific UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, orientation

I have been developing an app for iPad and it support only landscape, which mean it can rotate LandscapeLeft or LandscapeRight. For a specific UIViewController i want it to only stay on LandscapeLeft which it cannot rotate.

The situation is :
I have a UINavigationController to hold fews UIViewController. One of the UIViewController will push to a TabBarController. In TabBarController, there is an item(UIViewController) i only want in LandscapeLeft. This View Controller has another UINavigation Controller.

So Basically the mind map is look like this:

```
     UINavigationController
        |        \          \
     UIViewCon  UIViewCon  UIViewCon
        |
     TabBarCon
        |
      UINavigationCon
       |
    UIViewController(this is it)
```

I have tried most the solution on the internet but it doesn't work for me. The solution included create **Category** file of **UINavigationController** and override `shouldAutoRotate` and `supportedOrientation`. Hope you guys can help me out.

Comment: you mean subclass UINavigationController and override? instead of category? Since that's not really the purpose of categories.